# How to upload file by selenium and python on linux or Mac operator system

Tags: selenium, web, web-crawler

I write a web spider use python and selenium, want to upload file by browser automaticly. I found many solution based on '' label, and others need on Windows. Browser can be chrome, firefox or phantomjs.
is there anyone have the similar problem?

HTML

```
content<div class="upload-block upload-block-media action-upload"> 
<div class="upload-block-con"> <i class="icon icon-add-upload-b"> </i> </div> 
<div class="uploadPlaceholder" id="btn-upload-video"
style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;"> </div> </div>
```

Comment: this is HTML content<div class="upload-block upload-block-media action-upload">
                <div class="upload-block-con">
                    <i class="icon icon-add-upload-b">
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div class="uploadPlaceholder" id="btn-upload-video" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;">
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: I moved your HTML to question, it should not be in comments.